# JavaScript - use image as JSON value?

Tags: javascript, json, base64

I need to include images as value within a JSON file, but I do not know how.

I have a JavaScript file in JSON format, which contains the description for bike routes, like this:

```
var bikeRoutes = {
  "Route1": 
    {
      "title": "here goes the title",
      "description": "here goes the description", 
      "image": "path_to_the_image"
    },
  "Route2": 
    {
      "title": "here goes the title",
      "description": "here goes the description", 
      "image": "path_to_the_image"
  };
```

In my HTML file I access the JavaScript file looping through the file to get the information, like this:

```
document.getElementById("bikeRoutes").innerHTML += "<p>" + bikeRoutes[i].title 
+ "</p><br><p>" + bikeRoutes[i].description + "</p><br><img src='" +
bikeRoutes[i].image + "'>"
```

For the image, it does not work, I also tried to specify the html image element within the description of the JSON, but with no success. I get the error:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

As far as I could find out, it is not that easy to put a image within a JSON-formatted file. One work around seems to be to convert the image to base64.

I have in total 50 bike routes with about 100 images in sum, and the code resulting from the base64 Online Editor (https://www.base64-image.de) is so much "text" for one image, that my file is not manageable (readable) any more. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: Do you use `path_to_the_image` or base64 representation of image in your JSON?

Comment: just a wild guess, but could it be that your `path_to_the_image` is a local path? something like `C:\...`? if not, are aou using absolute, relative or root-relative paths? and have you checked them? Wether the browser tries to fetch the image from the right place. I'd dislike the idea of putting data-URIs into your JSON file. Besides how big are these images (filesize not dimensions)?

Comment: The path_to_the_image is a local path, but relative, like "image": "../images/bikeRoute1.jpeg". So it steps one folder back from the html page and then goes into the images folder. The images are 100kb per image. Should it theoretically be possible, that the html code only gets the path and image name and creates it, just as I tried it to work?

Comment: `Should it theoretically be possible, that the html code only gets the path and image name and creates it` That should not only be possible, imo. this is the way to go. Have you checked the images in the network-tab of dev-tools of the browser? Does it try to get the files from the right path? What does the server respond? And please, get rid of `.innerHTML +=`. First build the whole string and then assign it to `.innerHTML =` all at once.

Comment: `The images are 100kb per image.` and `...with about 100 images in sum...` *100kb* filesize means *~133kb* as base64. That times *100* images equals about **13MB** of string you're about to put in the JSON file. *100 x 100kb* this seems like *A LOT* of pixels you're about to render here at once. Have you considered getting rid of a bit of that payload? Like by showing only thumbnails. And minifying the images.

Comment: Found my error: the images are loaded within the index.html not the JavaScript (JSON), so it can directly go into the images folder without stepping back one folder level! This would have been only true when the images would have been loaded from the JavaScript, which is in another folder. Thank you! @Thomas: Is it still too much data if they are loaded directly from their source without parsing them into base64? The images would be on the server and loaded from there..

Comment: @Thomas: I create a sidebar with all bike routes, so I basically loop through the JSON file, getting one JSON object (is one bike route) within each run, that's why I use +=innerHTML, because otherwise the html would always be replaced by the next JSON object (biking route) - is +=innerHTML bad practise and if so, do you see any other possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my example and adjust your core correspondingly:

```
let data = {
  Route1: {
    "title": "here goes the title",
    "description": "here goes the description", 
    "image": `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7`
    },
  Route2: {
    "title": "here goes the title",
    "description": "here goes the description", 
    "image": "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
  }
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(bike => {
  let tmpl = `<p>${data[bike].title}</p><br>
    <p>${data[bike].description}</p>
    <img src="${data[bike].image}">`;
  document.getElementById("bikeRoutes").innerHTML += tmpl;
});
```

P.S jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/wk78h7eo/)

Comment: please, not `innerHTML+=`. Better `let rows = Object.keys(data).map(bike => { ... return tmpl });`and then `document.getElementById("bikeRoutes").innerHTML = rows.join("\n");`

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo: I try to fully understand your code to implement it. Is the "bike" in .forEach(bike...) chosen by yourself and then used in data[bike]?

Comment: bike is a key of your object `Route1` and `Route2`, sorry for naming non transparency..

Comment: Ok, but you could use any value (eg. biking, route, ...) instead of bike, right?

Comment: sure - it's up to you, it's just iterated item

Comment: thanks! One last question: For some routes I have one, for other two images. How can I handle this dynamic amount of images, making two keys for the potential images?

Comment: try smth like this `{Route1: {title: "a", desc: "b", images: ["url1", "url2"]}}`

Comment: yeah, why not! ;)